# ERROR install nvidia 440 on Ubuntu 18.04:Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-101-generic (x86_64)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

I'm trying to unstall nvidia-396 and install  nvidia-440 on my fresh Ubuntu 18.04.
and I get this error

[image: Error messaage]

make.log show:

```
cc: error: unrecognized command line option 鈥?fstack-protector-strong鈥?scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.82/build/nvidia/nv.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.82/build/nvidia/nv.o] Error 1
cc: error: unrecognized command line option 鈥?fstack-protector-strong鈥?scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.82/build/nvidia/nv-pci.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.82/build/nvidia/nv-pci.o] Error 1
Makefile:1577: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.82/build' failed
make[2]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.82/build] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-101-generic'
Makefile:81: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I have no idea of what's wrong